# Disable Application Insights Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights

We have an EPiServer website, which has Application Insights activated. This creates two cookies `ai_user` and `ai_session`. We would like to disable these cookies.

Based on information I found we can set the following:

> **isCookieUseDisabled** - Default false. If true, the SDK will not store
>   or read any data from cookies. **isStorageUseDisabled** - If true, the SDK
>   will not store or read any data from local and session storage.
>   Default is false. **enableSessionStorageBuffer** - Default true. If true,
>   the buffer with all unsent telemetry is stored in session storage. The
>   buffer is restored on page load

I was told this needs to go in: `ApplicationInsights.config`

But the syntax appears to be quite different from that file.

Do these settings need to go in the JS file instead? (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js)

If yes, where in Azure Monitor do I find the link to this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationInsights.config is for server side telemetry (Asp.Net) only, and not for client side monitoring using javascript.

Your settings to disable cookie (`isCookieUseDisabled`) should be part of Javascript snippet which enables application insights javascript monitoring. 
This is the official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#configuration